# Android app fails to connect to interenet on some devices, but not others

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that has several features which use HTTPConnection to connect to the internet and download data. I have tested on several devices, but the connection inside the app seems to be hit or miss on different devices. I be;lieve that the connection did not work on Samsung devices. I'm thinking that because it is not yet an "official" licensed application, that the connection is failing. Could it be some sort of OS difference?

The code below is supposed to connect to the internet and download words to a file. It works on some devices, but on others it ends up creating a blank file with and throwing an exception.

```
 try{ 
         URL url = new URL("*" + currQuickList + ".txt");
           URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
           urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
           int i = 0;  

               // Read all the text returned by the server
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String str;
        int count = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int[] a = createOrderedList(count,quickListLen);
        int d = 0;
        int g = 0;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null && d < a.length) {
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline
            // character(s)

            if(a[d] == g)
            {words.add(str);
            d++;
            }
            g++;

        }

             in.close();


                OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(dir);  
                 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo);
                 p.print(packageWords2(words) +"\n");

                 p.close();
                 fo.close();

                 System.out.println("file created: "+dir);
                 //files.add(wordText);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errorDialog(e);
                }
```

Comment: Well you probably have an error in your code but without it we cant tell you anything.

Comment: I agree with @fonZ, could you provide your code?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, for example capture logcat logs from the non-working devices.  As a totally random guess, if you failed to do your networking on a background thread, it could fail on newer devices but (at least in easy cases) work fine on older ones.

Comment: I've provided some code. See above.

Answer (score 2):

Check your internet connection before download or using internet .You can try this

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```